# Why listing go modules dependencies fail when the module is in my GOPATH?

Tags: go

I am using this project https://github.com/sttts/beerdb. When I clone in into /tmp/, if I run:

`go list -m all`

I get a list of all the dependencies. If the same project is in my 
`$GOPATH/src/github.com/stts/beerdb`, and then I run the same command I get:

`go list -m: not using modules`

If in both cases I am in the path where go.mod and go.sum are present, why I get a different behaviour? My go version is go1.12

Comment: Because in go 1.12 GOPATH mode is the default. Either set `GO11MODULE=on` env var, or better, use the latest 1.13 go.

Comment: I see, thanks! Could your comment become an answer so that I can say it is the answer to my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go 1.12 only has preliminary support for modules (introduces in Go 1.11). GOPATH is the default mode, but when `GO111MODULE` env var is set to `on`, the `go` command now supports module-aware operations outside of a module directory. For details, see [Go 1.12 Release notes: Modules](https://golang.org/doc/go1.12#modules).

Recommended to switch to Go 1.13 which added full module support. In Go 1.13 module-aware mode is active by default whenever a `go.mod` file is found in, or in a parent of, the current directory.